# VS2012 Code Coverage For Assemblies Not Covered By Tests Yet

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, mstest, code-coverage

I'm using code coverage in VS2012 premium as a diagnostic tool.

It appears to only provide code coverage results for assemblies that have code touched by a test.

I have some assemblies that aren't tested at all, I would like these to show as 0% coverage, rather than be ignored completely.

How can I force them to be covered?

I have a custom CodeCoverage.runsettings file that explicitly includes these assemblies, but they are still ignored.

Thanks,
Tim

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is by design. Check those assemblies loaded during the test run. You can only see the coverage of the code/assemblies loaded by your tests. In other words during your test execution, those assemblies must loaded into the memory so they can be instrumented. I think some other third party coverage tools shows the coverage if non instrumented assemblies but I'm not sure.

From MSDN:

> Code coverage analysis is done while tests are running. It only
>   includes assemblies that are loaded into memory when the tests run. If
>   none of the tests are executed then there is nothing for code coverage
>   to report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159523.aspx

Comment: Thanks.
So Microsoft in their wisdom decide to ignore assemblies I've explicitly said I want included because they have 0% coverage. Exactly the ones I want flagged.
The best solution though is to start adding some tests ;-)